# Storing data in the inode structure in Minix?

Tags: file, filesystems, inode, minix

I need to modify inode.h in Minix to hold an attribute called "classification level." I cannot find anything specifically about storing a simple int (classification level is just going to range from 0 to 5) in the inode struct.

I've found this link: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Documentation/Minix3/Inode.pdf 
Which talks about alloc_zone--but it looks as if it is for longer data.

Am I able just to add

```
int class_level;
```

under the other struct definitions or am I going to have to go through the whole zone allocation thing?